# ERROR Unknown lifecycle phase "compil"

Tags: java, maven

I correctly installed maven in my PC:

```
root@debian:/home/geekos# mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 16:22:22+0100)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-4-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Then i tried to compile a maven project exist in my /home/geekos, i did:

```
root@debian:/home/geekos# mvn compil
```

He founds the project, he starts building it but i got a problem:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building QR Code 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.114s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 31 20:22:38 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "compil". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Comment: Give "compile" a shot. More lifecycles [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `maven` phase is called `compile` not `compil`.